# Find points of vector that have min euclidean distance in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

In R I have two vectors

```
a = c(25,24,25)
b = c(33,33,32,31,26)
```

I'm using `dist()` function to calculate the euclidean distance of the values of the `a,b` vectors.

I want to find the value of `b` that has minimum distance from a point in `a`.

Currently my code is:

```
 minDist = min(dist(c(a,b), method="euclidean"))
```

How can I find the points that have min distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather proceed like this:

```
m = outer(a,b, FUN=function(x,y) (x-y)**2)

which(m==min(m), arr.ind=T)
     row col
[1,]   1   5
[2,]   3   5
```

Stating that element `5` in `b` is the closest to element `1` and `3` in `a`.

Indeed:

```
#> m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   64   64   49   36    1
#[2,]   81   81   64   49    4
#[3,]   64   64   49   36    1
```

Instead of `outer`, a ***fast*** solution would be:

```
nc = length(b)
nr = length(a)
m  = (matrix(a, ncol=nc, nrow=nr) - matrix(b, ncol=nc, nrow=nr, byrow=T))**2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you explain me the result of which please? The result is `b[5]` and `a[3]` as well? So if the result of which is stored in `w`, what would the result look like?

Comment: I added some explanation ;) It depends on the order you proceed with `outer` (we could have wrote `outer(b,a, ...)`)

Comment: Got it! Just saw your edited response! Thank you a lot!